# Visual Studio: how to change cell colour based on cell value, but can be hundreds of different possibilities

Tags: visual-studio, colors, expression, cell

I have a report which has a table inside a table and I want a cell colour to be based on the value of the cell, as linked to, or looked up from, another associated value.

In essence, it is a seating grid for an exam hall, with parameters for Date, Session, and Room.  The main grid is generated by the seat column and row values e.g. A01, A02, through to U21, U22.  Inside that are the details of who will sit at each desk and which exam it is for e.g. subject A, subject B. Subject A cells need to be coloured pink, Subject B need to be coloured Blue etc.

I do have a table which lists the subject in one column and the colour in another. Both fields are VarChar.

There are 800 different subjects and 400 different sittings, so I can't create a new rule to specify each one as there are too many: it has to be based on the cell value and the colour looked up from that value.

I have tried putting an expression in the cell to determine the colour, but can't get the right expression as I can't get it to look up the cell value and cross reference the subject to the appropriate colour.

How can I do that please?

I am very new to Visual Studio and creating the report has pushed at the limits of my knowledge so please do explain carefully any suggestions. I certainly have no idea which language Visual Studio uses so apologies if I have used the wrong tag.   Thank you!!

Comment: This was tagged Visual Studio Code, but says "Visual Studio".  It is also unclear if you are coding something at all... at the moment this sounds more like a "Microsoft Excel" question...

Comment: on a different sheet define the color lookup tables for the different columns and use `VLOOKUP` or `HLOOKUP` to get a color based on cell value